# How can I show a "selection highlighting"-rectangle around a column of a Silverlight Grid?

Tags: silverlight, grid, selection

I have a feature matrix implemented with Silverlight's `Grid` where users need to select a product.  How can I indicate selection with a rectangle around the whole selected column?

It is easy to put a CheckBox at the bottom of each product's column, but that is too dull.  I would have preffered to use SL Toolkit's `DataGrid` (with built-in row selection), but it cannot be orientated vertically for a feature matrix...

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to place a rectangle round the contents of a whole column in a Silverlight Grid you simply place the Rectangle as the last child item in the Grid and assign the property `Grid.RowSpan` on it to the number of rows in the grid and `Grid.Column` to the column you wish to highlight.  E.g.:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Row Definitions (say 4 in this case)-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Column definitions -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Grid contents -->

    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1" />

</Grid>
```

Having said that it would seem to be hard work to manage a `Grid` to display something data driven like a product matrix.  You state that a `DataGrid` would work for you if it could render "rows" horizontally.  Well a `ListBox` can be styled that way so that is what I'd been inclined to use.

Comment: How would you style a ListBox to do this?  Matrix cells can contain several lines of text and I could not find a way to align cell heights without the Grid.

Comment: @carlmon: Ah ok I see your problem, with difficulty ;)  The correct level to create such a control would be to derive from `Selector` and create your own custom panel and panel item controls to be displayed.  Whilst this would be a more complete solution its probably a lot harder than what you are already doing.